# playing divx on my ipad

Tags: ipad, divx

I use windows7. I have an Ipad and my goal is to transfer some of my divx movies to my ipad.
I tried it all through itunes on windows and could not find a solution:
someone has a solution ?

regards

Comment: This has nothing to do with software development. Try superuser.com.

Comment: not even superuser - maybe ipad.stackexchange.com ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not really a programming question.

Check out the free VLC app in iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

VLC is the best tool to use. If you're looking to watch videos from your local network, you can even use apps like Air Video Share or Zumocast and those display videos without having the video on your device.

Download VLC, [here](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html).